# CloudKit no longer working after App Store deployment

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, cloudkit

I just put an app on the store, and it uses CloudKit. The version that I get straight from the computer worked perfectly, but when others (or I) download from the App Store the information will not download from the cloud. If I hook it back up to the computer and try again it works again!! It's the exact same code on the same phone why does it interact differently with the cloud when downloading from the App Store!?

Comment: you should add your code. look for error messages in the logs on your phone (for the deployed app)

Comment: Did you test it on TestFlight before deploying to the store? TestFlight beta testing uses the production database for CloudKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CloudKit dashboard go to Deployment en press the 'Deploy to production' button